# Python converting nested dictionary with list containing float elements as individual elements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm collecting values from different arrays and nested dictionary containing list values, like below. The lists contains millions of rows, I tried pandas dataframe concatenation But getting out of memory, so I resorted to a for loop.

```
array1_str = ['user_1', 'user_2', 'user_3','user_4' , 'user_5']
array2_int = [3,3,1,2,4]
nested_dict_w_list = {'outer_dict' : { 'inner_dict' : [[1.0001],[2.0033],[1.3434],[2.3434], [0.44224]}}
    
final_out = [array1_str[i], array2_int[i], nested_dict_w_list['outer_dict']['inner_dict'][array2_int[i]]] for i in range(len(array2_int))]
```

I'm getting the output as

```
user_1, 3, [2.3434]
user_2, 3, [2.3434]
user_3, 1, [1.0001]
user_4, 2, [1.3434]
user_5, 4, [0.44224]
```

But I want the output as

```
user_1, 3, 2.3434
user_2, 3, 2.3434
user_3, 1, 1.0001
user_4, 2, 1.3434
user_5, 4, 0.44224
```

I need to eventually convert this to parquet file, I'm using spark dataframe to convert this to parquet, but the schema is appearing as array(double)). But I need it as just double.  Any input is appreciated.

The below for loop is working, but any other efficient and elegant solution.

```
final_output = []
for i in range(len(array2_int)-1)):
  index = nested_dict_w_list['outer_dict']['inner_dict'][array2_int[i]]
  final_output.append(array1_str[i], array2_int[i], index[0])
```

Comment: Can you please improve the provided code? `outer_dict` and `inner_dict` are both not defined. Also, for `final_out`, syntax is not valid as you must have brackets around the values in the list comprehension and `nested_dict_w_list` is indexed with `inner_dict`, while on the top level it only has `outer_dict` as a key

Comment: You have added a snippet that you say works for you, however, it has multiple syntax issues: `array_2` doesn't exist. `len(array_2 - 1)` is not correct, as you cannot subtract 1 from an array. `inner_dict` is still undefined in your code, and `nested_dict_w_list` still only has `outer_dict` in it's top level keys

Comment: @tituszban, I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your original list comprehension, by indexing to item zero:

```
final_out = [
    (array1_str[i], array2_int[i], nested_dict_w_list['outer_dict']['inner_dict'][array2_int[i]][0])
    for i in range(len(array2_int))
]
```

Comment: OMG, why didn't i think of that ... :)

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable error, but I'm not iterating on the float object itself. any idea why?

Comment: Based on the data you have provided this works. I cannot help without you providing any more information